# Does different wire matter?

Tags: wiring

I see that it's common for red wire to be positive and black to be negative mostly in DC battery, but would it matter if you switch the wire?

Comment: I'm really not sure what to tell you: obviously it will matter, as soon as you go back and wonder what you did there, or if someone else gets into problems because you violated that clear convention.

Comment: Could you please clarify by editing the question if you mean just to swap the _colors_, or also swap (+) and (-)?

Comment: Are you asking about COLOR of the insualtion? Or are you asking about exchanging POLARITY (positive and negative)? Your question is ambiguous as written and cannot be answered properly.

Answer (score 5):

In the electrical circuit the wire is a wire!! The electrons will have no concept of the wire insulation color. So you could use any color and the circuit would work the same.

The things that may affect the circuit performance in any given case would include:

1. What diameter the wire has
2. The length of the wire
3. Whether the wire is solid or stranded
4. The metal used for the wire conductor
5. The type of insulation material on the wire

On the other hand the color conventions used to delineate common wire usages are put in place by humans for humans. There are many factors at play regarding these conventions but here are a few:

1. Safety of persons inspecting circuitry
2. Help in understanding how things are hooked up when troubleshooting a circuit when you do not have full documentation
3. Assisting in sorting out which wire is which when a bundle of wires are used together in a long harness or cable

Answer (score 2):

1. The COLOR of the insulation makes absolutely no difference.  HOWEVER...
2. Switching which wire is connected to positive or negative (without regard to color) will typically RUIN/TOAST/BLOW UP most anything electronic. Of course incandescent lamps don't care, and DC motors will typically run in the opposite direction if you switch the polarity.

It is not clear whether you are asking about whether the COLOR is important, or whether you are asking if the POLARITY is important. It would be helpful for you to clarify exactly what you are asking.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this will help much, but it's original.

> There was a young man from Stansted
>   Who got black wire swapped with his red.
>   "Who cares if it's proper?
>   Current flows through the copper."
>   Now his car's runing backwards instead.

Comment: It would be good if it went backwards, rather than bang!!

Comment: It pains me to upvote this, because it's definitely _not_ an answer, but sometimes it's just worth it.

Comment: Good man! It _does_ succinctly cover many of the points raised in the other answers.

Comment: Considering how naive the question is, this is a worthy answer +1.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, the functional part of a wire is the conductor itself which provides the low impedance path for charge flow via electrons, and if included, then also the insulation around it which provides a barrier against that flow where it's not wanted. The color of the insulation around it has nothing functional about it, from the point of view of the functioning electronics or electrical system.

The color is instead there for people to see. If you want to make a circuit, have the ability to own more than one color of insulation with the wire you use to make it, and you imagine that others may someday explore your circuit or otherwise need to actively modify any of it, then you should try and be "conventional" in your use of colors to the degree you are able to do so. The color of the insulation is about communication and, as a result of good communication, also an aide towards better safety as well. (It may also help others protect their own equipment when attempting to apply instrumentation of some kind, such as for measuring voltages.)

Comment: So the color is to stay organize and the wire within such as metal or copper is what really matter if for example you your own color coded wire?

Comment: Yes. The copper or silver or aluminum is the conductor which allows an easy pathway. The insulator shields that conductor so that only at the ends does it intentionally connect things -- it keeps other conductors from accidentally brushing across it where it would be unintended. The color is for you and me and others to see and to act as a guide of sorts.

Answer (score 1):

If you switched the wires to a filament lamp, it would light just fine.

If you switched the wires to a permanent magnet motor, it would run backwards.

If you switched the wires to an LED, it would break, never to work again.

If you switched the colours of the wires, but left the copper connectivity exactly the same, everything would work just fine and dandy, at first. If you or somebody else came to mend, troubleshoot or extend the circuit, and they were not aware, or you had forgotten, that you were using non-standard colours, then it's likely that something would get connected backwards, and go bang.

Answer (score 0):

Considering conventional charge flow, it's been true, since the beginning of time, that a red jacket indicates that that wire is connected to the positive terminal of the DC power supply (which bleeds) and a black jacket indicates that that wire is connected to the negative terminal of the DC supply - the color of earth, to which blood returns.